# How to simulate a button click using HttpClient

Tags: c#, .net, rest, web

I am trying to navigate to a REST API, however the owner of the web page has inserted an HTML message page in front of the REST API URL.  So, when I make the request to the REST API, instead of being returned the XML file that I requested, I get back an HTML page that has some informational message on it, and requires a button click to acknowledge the message.

The button itself, when inspected with Fiddler, shows no onclick event:

```
<div class="dialog-buttons">
    <button id="frmMessages:btnAcknowledge" name="frmMessages:btnAcknowledge" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" onclick="" title="Acknowledge and continue" type="submit">
        <span class="ui-button-text ui-c">OK</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

I am not able to navigate directly to the page where the button-click sends you, because it doesn't send you anywhere, it just acknowledges that you clicked the button, and closes the message.

I am trying to simulate this button click.  I have tried using a System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser class, but I have not been able to load my resultContent into the Browser, the DocumentText property remains empty, so when I try to invoke the button click, I get a null reference exception.

```
handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.CookieContainer = cookies;
handler.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

using (var client = new HttpClient(handler)){
    string resultContent = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser b = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();
    b.Navigate("about:blank");
    HtmlDocument doc = b.Document;
    doc.Write(string.Empty);
    b.DocumentText = resultContent;
    var resp = b.Document.GetElementById("frmMessages:btnAcknowledge").InvokeMember("onclick");
}
```

It seems to me that the owner of the web page screwed something up here by inserting the HTML message page in front of a REST API call, and I have contacted them about that, however between now and when they can fix it (if it is even an issue to them) I need a method of bypassing this message box.

Comment: Have you tried `doc.Write(resultContent)` ?

Comment: HttpClient is not associated with any kind of user interface, and therefore it cannot simulate any user input events directly. I would play around in the browser and check if there is any network activity when the button is clicked, but you sad it doesn't "send you anywhere". If you refresh the page in the browser, do you have to click the button again every time?

Comment: @MihalyBalas You're right regarding HttpClient, that's why I tried to use the WebBrowser class.  Checked the browser activity, I'm sent to a sign-on page first, then re-directed to my initial request URL, however I get the HTML message after I am returned from the sign-on page.  I contacted the IT department overseeing the page, and they see the same problem and are looking into it.  After I acknowledge the message box, I get a 403 error for trying to view REST webservice in a browser.  If I reload this page, I get the same 403 error.  If I Reload the message page, I get the same message box.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The owner of the website fixed the issue on their end.  I was never able to find a way to do this, but the issue has been resolved.